# Jquery chosen trigger method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-chosen

I'am using  ***jquery-chosen plugin***. I want to set option **"selected"** by index value. Following codes are working right but I guess the plugin has a bug.

Because when I give number upper than zero it works fine but when I give zero it doesnt work . How I can fix it ? Thanks in advance

```
$('#mySlelectID').val(index).trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: Ok , thank you wait a minute pls, I'll share .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/resul92/85yf8fL4/

Answer (score 1):

There are so many issue in your code, firstly your `option` tags do not have `value` attribute in it, secondly jquery library is not included in your jsfiddle example. After resolving these issue, you can make any value selectd by using:

```
jQuery('.chosen').val(1).change();
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85yf8fL4/1/)

Comment: I have just complete my code. https://jsfiddle.net/resul92/85yf8fL4/  . Here it is work which you are write.But in my project it works different :/

Comment: Again the `value` attribute missing and jquery is to missing and because of this console is full or errors